# C- Structs with Assigning Char *

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to assign values into the my structs. However, I'm finding some difficulty. I would like to create a list that holds users, titles, and views.

I have a struct as shown below

```
struct table{
    char *user[50];
    char *title[50];
    int views;
}
```

I get the information from a text file and I'm trying to read the text file line by line and assigning the values accordingly.

```
 struct table *tables;
 tables = malloc(50*sizeof(struct table));
 FILE *ptr_file;
 char *name_file="2012-11-05-13-34.txt"; //change this later

 ptr_file=fopen(name_file, "r"); 
 if(!ptr_file)
    printf("Couldn't open file %s for reading.\n", name_file);

 printf("Opened file %s for reading.\n", name_file);

 line_number = 0;
 while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), ptr_file) != NULL){
    if(strcmp(buffer, "") == 0)
       return 0;
    char *views=strtok(buffer, ",");
    char *name=strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *title=strtok(NULL, ",");
    tables[line_number].views=atoi(views);
    strcpy(tables[line_number].user, user);
    strcpy(tables[line_number].title, title);
    line_number++;
 }
```

I'm getting errors like char*_restricted_but argument is type char**. I was wondering if anyone can help explain this to me or if they can direct me to anywhere I can get some examples I can look through.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct table` doesn't nave a `name` member its `user`.

Also you have `user` and `title` declared as an array of pointers, but try to use them to hold strings, use char arrays instead.

```
struct table{
    char user[50];
    char title[50];
    int views;
}
```

--EDIT--

If you want to keep the array of pointers (for sorting or whatever), you are going to have to allocate memory for each one to store your strings.

```
 while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), ptr_file) != NULL){
    if(strcmp(buffer, "") == 0)
       return 0;
    char *views=strtok(buffer, ",");
    char *name=strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *title=strtok(NULL, ",");
    tables[line_number].views=atoi(views);
    tables[line_number].user[0] = strdup(user);  // 
    tables[line_number].title[0] = strdup(title);// 
    line_number++;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed name to user. I would like to keep these as char * pointers because I will be later using these to sort.